# Encrypt Cipher RSA Public Key NodeJS From Java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, rsa, public-key

I need to implement encrpytion in NodeJS using public key RSA from java language to encrypt HttpPost params.

```
public class RSAUtil {
    public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(key.getBytes());
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
        return publicKey;
    }        
    public static String encrypt(String publicKeyFrom, byte[] waitEncrypt) throws Exception {
        String publicK = publicKeyFrom.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKey(publicK);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(1, publicKey);
        int inputLen = waitEncrypt.length;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int offSet = 0;        
        for (int i = 0; inputLen - offSet > 0; offSet = i * 117) {
            byte[] cache;
            if (inputLen - offSet > 117) {
                cache = cipher.doFinal(waitEncrypt, offSet, 117);
            } else {
                cache = cipher.doFinal(waitEncrypt, offSet, inputLen - offSet);
            }        
            out.write(cache, 0, cache.length);
            ++i;
        }        
        byte[] encryptedData = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedData);
    }
}
```

And here is how to use it in Java.

```
String PUBLIC_KEY = "MIIBIjANxxxxxxxxlGqQIDAQAB";
String reqParams = "{\"code\":\"A12345\"}";
String encryptedParams = RSAUtil.encrypt(PUBLIC_KEY, reqParams.getBytes());
```

And I already tried to translate the code into NodeJS as follow.

```
const Crypto = require('crypto');
const encryptParams = function (params, publicKey) {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(params)
    const encrypted = Crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer)
    const ecryptedParams = encrypted.toString('base64');
    return ecryptedParams;
}

const PUBLIC_KEY = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANxxxxxxxxlGqQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;
const reqParams = { code: 'A12345' };
const encryptedParams = encryptParams(JSON.stringify(reqParams), PUBLIC_KEY);
```

But as long as I used the encrptedParams from NodeJS code to existing Java code HttpPost, it does not work. And if I used encrptedParams from Java to NodeJS Axios it works.

Could you please help pointing me out what is wrong with my NodeJS code? or show me the correct way to have encryption from above Java code into NodeJS code?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show what is `Crypto` class is in your Node.js code.

Comment: it is from built in crypto library in NodeJS, i used v11.10.0